# llaves primarias y foraneas al mismo tiempo?? Mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, oracle, modelorelacional

tengo 3 tablas:

```
producto
* id_producto, 
* nombre
* etc.
```

otra que es

```
atributo
* id_atributo
* id_categoria
* etc.
```

y

```
atributo_producto
* id_producto
* id_atributo
* valor
```

Entonces, yo en la tabla atributo_producto tenía ademas de esos campos que se ven un campo id_atrib_prod que era la llave primaria de esa tabla, pero me dijeron que no es necesario ese campo y que los campos id_producto e id_atributo eran las unicas que deberían de existr pero en ese caso no existiría una llave primaria para esa tabla y la única opción que queda es que esos 2 campos (id_producto, id_atributo) que son llaves foráneas de otras tablas, deben ser también llaves primarias ahí en la tabla atributo_producto.

Entonces, en el modelo relacional; es correcto que exista una tabla con 2 llaves foraneas que a la vez deben ser llaves primarias??

Adjunto imagen de la tabla de la que hablo:

[image: tabla atributo_producto con 2 llaves foraneas que a la vez son primarias en esa tabla]

Comment: SI, es correcto... que problema le ves a eso?

Comment: No le veo ningun problema, solo quería que alguien me dijera si es correcto o no una tabla con tal estructura porque nunca había visto algo asi. Eso que acabo de hacer es un tipo de llave primaria compuesta??

Comment: Me parece no se que lo que veo ahí es una relación de muchos a muchos, quue como tal ya te mencionaron es correctaç

Comment: y la relación de N:N no debería romperse según las FN1, FN2 y FN3?? o si te refieres a las patitas de gallo que se observan en la imagen, son las relaciones 1:N con las otras tablas. La que está en el lado derecho es la relación hacia la tabla producto y la que está abajo es la relación con la tabla atributo.

Comment: ¿Qué es una llave primaria? Es una columna o conjunto de columnas que identifican cada fila de la tabla de forma única. Si la combinación de dos o más columnas de tu tabla satisfacen esa condición, pueden perfectamente ejercer de llave primaria sin necesidad de otra (autoincremental por ejemplo).

Comment: La pregunta es para MySql o para Oracle?